# Collapsing toolbar with 16:9 image and text below

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my application I want to create a collapsing toolbar with an image below the status bar at 16:9 ratio. Under the image should be some text on a white background. I tried to do it like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
     ... android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
         ... android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

         <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
             ... android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

             <ImageView
                 ... android:id="@+id/cover_image"
                 app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
             />

             <TextView
                 ... app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cover_image"
             />
         />

         <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            ... />

     />

    <!-- other content -->
/>
```

My problem with this is, that the whole `ConstraintLayout` is moved upwards below the statusbar and therefore creates a gap between the text and the main content. This is because the adjusted padding of `fitsSystemWindows` is only applied to the first child of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. My only solution for this is to create a second `ConstraintLayout` as first child of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` which holds the image and replace the image of the text layout with a placeholder view which has the exact same apsect ratio so that the text goes below the image.

This feels a bit hacky. Have I missed something here or is there an easier solution?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If yes could you please share the answer?

Comment: Yes I did, look at the last answer here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/520

Answer (score 0):

The following is only an example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/album_art"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="230dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="ABCD ABCD"
                    android:textColor="#443366"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/Toolbar"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Please notice: in this code snippet, the AppBar height is 260dp, ImageView is 230dp to make room for the TextView. If you set the height of the ImageView to match_parent, the TextView might go out of sight!
#screenshot of previous code example:
[image]

Comment: I know it works with specific heights but I want the 16:9 aspect ratio which only works with ConstraintLayout